# How can I get this mouse to joystick program to work?

Tags: c++, qt

I've recently bought Tie-Fighter Special Edition on Steam but have found that it requires a joystick to play. I have been looking for a solution to this, and have found [this code](https://github.com/raptorswing/MouseToJoystick) which supposedly converts mouse input to joystick input. However, I've been having trouble getting it to work.

I do not have any experience with C++ or Qt Creator, meaning that I really do not know what I need to do to get this to work. I suspect that it may have been written using an older version of Qt.

When I try to compile the code in Visual Studio, I get several errors saying that it cannot open any of the source files.

```
cannot open source file "QApplication"  
cannot open source file "QMainWindow"   
cannot open source file "QDateTime"
```

and so on...

If I try to open and build the code in Qt Creator, I get the error `File MakeFile doesn't exist`

I would really appreciate any help with this, as I'm stumped for what I need to change to get the code to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a version already compiled here

https://github.com/raptorswing/MouseToJoystick/releases